# Jmeter loop Count 'forever' does not run forever

Tags: loops, jmeter, load-testing, threadgroup

I have created a jmeter scrip for 25 users to login to system and perform some functions. I wanted to run that run that test plan forever. So i have selected Loop count "forever" option in test plan.But thread group doesn't run forever and its stoped automatically. Why this is Happening?
 Structure of Test Plan as below;

- Test Plan
- Thread group

  - HTTP Request Default
  - HTTP Cookie Manager
  - HTTP Cache Manager
  - CVS Data Set Config
  - Transaction Controller for Login
  - Transaction Controllers for Other functions
  - Transaction Controller for Logout
  - View Result Tree
  - Response Time Graph

Answer (score 3):

Double Check your [CSV Data Set Config](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) element and make sure that:

- "Recycle on EOF?" is **true**
- "Stop thread on EOF?" is **false**

Comment: Checked it. But there is no problem with those parameters.

Comment: Don't have any other ideas. I assume that "Scheduler" section of the Thread Group(s) is disabled as well. Check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries. If it doesn't help can you post it and your .jmx file somewhere so we could take a look?

Answer (score 1):

This is also can be done using [loop controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller).

Use 'loop controller' under 'Thread group' and segregate all your requests(*'25 users to login to system...'*) here, and keep Transaction Controller out of loop.

Here, it is also possible to use '[Simple Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller)' and segregate these requests.

Run jmeter script's using [console](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui), and disable components like 'View Result Tree' and 'Response Time Graph' it is best to [configure](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/) jmeter for memory leaks.